# Could u help me to explain the result of the C++ program?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

The output of this program is:

> A::Fun C::Do

Why it is not:

> A::Fun   A::do

It is mainly about how virtual function works, but I am not that familiar with it,actually I am totally a newcomer to C++, really need your patience,thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
private:
    int nVal;
public:
    void Fun() { cout << "A::Fun" << endl; }
    void Do()  { cout << "A::Do" << endl;  }
};

class B :public A {
public:
    virtual void Do() { cout << "B::Do" << endl; }
};

class C :public B {
public:
    void Do()  { cout << "C::Do" << endl; }
    void Fun() { cout << "C::Fun" << endl; }
};

void Call(B &p) {
    p.Fun();
    p.Do();
}

int main() {
    C c;
    Call(c);
}
```

Comment: Complie with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use a debugger** (`gdb` ) to run your program step by step. Read about [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) & [virtual method table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

neither function is virtual in A.

So in B we have:

- a virtual `Do` and
- an inherited non-virtual `Fun`.

---

```
p.Fun
```

Is pretty clear it calls `A::Fun`.

---

```
p.Do
```

it calls `C::Fun` because:

- `Do` is virtual in `B`,
- `C` overrides `Do`
- `p` is a reference type

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The call `p.Fun()` gets resolved to `A::Fun()` at compile time. Since it is not a `virtual` function, `A::Fun()` gets executed at run time too.

The call `p.Do()` gets resolved to `B::Do()` at compile time. Since it is a `virtual` function and the type corresponding to the real object, `C`, has an overridden implementation, `C::Do()` gets executed at run time.

Answer (score 0):

The output turns out to be

```
A::Fun
C::Do
```

The reason being B inherits from `A` and then the class `B` has no function of its own called `fun` so it is quite expected. Coming to the next output, It turns out that Even if the reference class `B` calls `Do`, it becomes the call to the derived class `C` why is that?

When a method becomes virtual, The call is no more decided upon the datatype of the object calling it, Rather it is the address which decides the call to that method. Since the method `Do` is virtual. call is now upon the address, The address basically belongs to 'C', so `C`'s `Do` is called, I hope you got it.

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I have got it, the call function has a B type of object as its argument and its address belongs to 'C'.